# c# add object array to ICollection - convert dto -> model

Tags: c#, dto, icollection

I need to convert this DTO

```
public class MyDTO
{
   [JsonProperty("studentInfo")]
   public StudentInfo studentInfo {get; set; }

   public class StudentInfo
   { 
      [JsonProperty("others")]
      public ICollection<AnotherDTO[]> Others { get; set; }
   }
   public class AnotherDTO
   {
       [JsonProperty("name")]
       public string name { get; set; }
   }

}
```

to this model

```
public class MyModel
{
   public StudentInfo studentInfo {get; set; }

   public class StudentInfo
   { 
      public ICollection<Another[]> Others { get; set; }
   }
   public class Another
   {
       public string name { get; set; }
   }

}
```

I am getting hung up on the ICollection. Here is the bit where I am trying to populate ICollection Others.

```
 private static ICollection<MyModel.Another[]> getAnothers(MyDTO myDTO, MyModel myModel)
 {  
    List<MyModel.Another> myList = new List<MyModel.Another>();
    foreach(var x in myDTO.studentInfo.Others)
    {
      foreach(var y in x)
      {
         myList.Add(new MyModel.Another
         {
             name = y.name
         });
      }

    }
 }
 MyModel.Another[] newList;
 newList = myList.ToArray();
 ICollection<MyDTO.AnotherDTO[]> ic = (ICollection<MyModel.Another[]>newList.Cast<MyModel.Another[]>().ToList();
```

This last line is giving me the following error:

Unable to cast object of type MyModel to type MyModel[].

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of manually mapping the object, I would suggest to use [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper). AutoMapper is a simple little library built to solve a deceptively complex problem - getting rid of code that mapped one object to another. You can also get Nuget package for AutoMapper

Just define the mapping for the objects -

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MyDTO, MyModel>();
```

..and simply map the object like this -

```
var myModelObject = Mapper.Map<MyModel>(myDtoObject);
```

Please refer [this](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started) getting started link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a select statement to convert the collection.

```
var myDto = new MyDto
{
    studentInfo = new MyModel.StudentInfo
    {
        Others = new List<AnotherDTO[]>
        {
            new[] 
            {
               new AnotherDTO { Name = "a" },
               new AnotherDTO { Name = "b" }
            },
            new[] 
            {
               new AnotherDTO { Name = "x" },
               new AnotherDTO { Name = "y" }
            }
        }
    }

    var model = new MyModel
    {
        studentInfo = new MyModel.StudentInfo
        {
            Others = dto.StudentInfo.Others
               .Select(otherDtoArray =>
                    otherDtoArray
                      .Select(otherDto => new MyModel.Other {Name = otherDto.Name})).ToList()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments everyone. My main problem was trying to convert the ICollection.

I ended up changing ICollection in my model to simply List. And it is working out nicely. I am not able to Use AutoMapper as was suggested, but I do see the value of it for case like mine.

Answer (score -1):

There's all kinds of wrong in your code.

```
foreach(var x in myDTO.studentInfo.Others)
{
  foreach(var y in x)
  {
     myList.Add(new MyModel.Another
     {
         name = y.name
     });
  }
```

Why do you need the 2nd foreach loop ? Your first foreach loop is already looping through your Others (type: ICollection). Each "x" is an instance of AnotherDTO.

Secondly, the following is completely wrong:

```
 MyModel.Another[] newList;
 newList = myList.ToArray();
 ICollection<MyDTO.AnotherDTO[]> ic = (ICollection<MyModel.Another[]>newList.Cast<MyModel.Another[]>().ToList();
```

`MyList` is already a list. You're then trying to cast it as an Array and then back to a list. There's no point in doing this.

Also, you might as well just not use `ICollection` at all. It's heavy for nothing. Just use `List`.

Also don't name variables with simple letters 'a', 'b', 'x', 'y', etc... You're going to get flamed by your colleagues once you're on the job market.

Here's the corrected version of your code:

```
public class SomeClass
{
 public static List<Another> MapAnotherDtoToAnother(List<AnotherDTO> others)
 {  
    List<Another> anotherList = new List<Another>();
    foreach(var anotherDto in others)
    {
        Another another = new Another();

        /* Populate fields of `another` whatever they are from `anotherDto` */
        another.FirstName = anotherDto.FirstName;

        anotherList.Add(another);
    }

    return anotherList;

 }
}
```

To convert an ICollection to List just do:

```
/* Convert your ICollection to a List */
List<AnotherDTO> AnotherDTOList = myDto.StudentInfo.Others.Cast<AnotherDTO>().ToList()

/* Use your static function get your non-dto counterpart */
List<Another> anothers = SomeClass.MapAnotherDtoToAnother(AnotherDTOList);
```

Hope it helps.
Good luck!

Comment: Others is an `ICollection<AnotherDTO[]>` (i.e. a list of arrays) 

Whether that is a good design decision is another question, but for the code as it stands, he absolutely needs the second foreach.